# Quran burning is a legit form of Quran disposal?

Tags: quran

- [What is the respectful way to dispose of Islam's holy book?](https://www.csmonitor.com/World/Global-News/2012/0221/Quran-burning-What-is-the-respectful-way-to-dispose-of-Islam-s-holy-book)

If Quran burning is a legitimate form of Quran disposal, why is Quran burning in Sweden/Norway seen as a heinous act by Muslims?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Disposing of the Quran by burning is disagreed upon. There are madhabs who consider it forbidden or makruh.
2. Disposal only applies to an unusable deteriorating copy. The reason is that fragments of the pages can break off and then be inadvertently trampled or mix with filth. Hence disposal methods are permitted as a way to ensure respect of the book. No one permits burning a usable copy of the Quran, let alone for the very purpose of disrespect.
3. You are comparing two different things. For example when you die it is permitted to bury your body in order to protect your dignity and the feelings of others from the effects of decomposition. But it is not permitted to bury you alive to murder you.

Comment: *Disposing of the Quran by burning is disagreed upon. There are madhabs who consider it forbidden or makruh.* --- What is the agreed up on method?

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/80599/32479